# Two monitor setup, icons / programs default to left screen all the time

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, cinnamon

I have dual monitor setup with my right monitor being my primary one. When I run a program or create an icon it always appears on the left monitor instead of the right one, even though the right monitor is set to primary.

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 with cinnamon desktop using nvidia drivers.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: In case you do, I added an asnwer to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/568438/make-fullscreen-applications-launch-on-righ-hand-monitor

Comment: You might be running into the same issue I am, which I filed under https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1425000

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu doesn't care what the primary monitor is (xconf "use this as my primary display" means nothing apparently), it uses the left/right arrangement of the screens to decide which is primary.  Whatever screen is 'left' in screen settings is the primary display.

This question has been asked before: [Change Primary monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863/change-primary-monitor)

This question is being asked again: [How to make the right hand monitor the primary monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/568438/make-fullscreen-applications-launch-on-righ-hand-monitor)

Hopefully someone out there knows how to get fullscreen applications to launch in right hand monitor.

Comment: I think it can be done, will try soon.