# Main screen constantly resets

Tags: multiple-monitors

Whenever I boot up Ubuntu, the default main screen is always the wrong one, if I set it to be on the right one its all fine and dandy, but once I restart my PC the main screen always goes back to be the wrong one,
is there a way to make ubuntu remember that?

fyi I am using the Nvidia X service to define the main screen. the settings there stay the same but I have to re-choose the screen for it to go back to normal.

I'm not that good at phrasing stuff so please point out whatever is not understandable and I will explain/define/edit what I meant or mean.

Comment: Is it about the initial login-screen, or is it after you have logged in? Or both?

Comment: I hope it is not outdatet https://askubuntu.com/questions/863/change-primary-monitor

Comment: Have you tried just using the Display settings in Ubuntu to set the default monitor?  I have an NVIDIA card and that is how I choose my default monitor and it holds just fine after each reboot.

Comment: I did fix the problem on the desktop, but the login screen is still messed up, also the mouse sensitivity on the login screen is much larger.