# NVIDIA X server settings missing a lot settings

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-settings

I wanted to stop the screen tearing problem that I encountered when installing NVIDIA drivers. This is not possible for me since there is no X Server Display Configuration tab to manually adjust the settings. I have searched the whole internet and found no answer to this (there is even a question in this about this but is has remained unanswered).

For the record, I have disabled the Secure Boot option, as someone suggested for a similar problem, but it didn't work.

[Settings panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRNe8.png)

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To help the community resolve your issue, and for future members who may encounter this issue in the future, can you please edit your question to include the make/model of your computer (and in this case, your GPU), and the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running. Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this section "X Server Display Configuration" might not be visible could be because your NVIDIA GPU is not set as a default GPU.
I had the same issue when using "NVIDIA On-Demand" mode in "NVIDIA X Server Settings -> PRIME Profiles". By changing to "NVIDIA Performance" mode it now shows that missing section.